# High-dimensional representation of arbitrary input

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, high-dimensional

Given a symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with positive entries and zero diagonal, is it always possible to construct a high-dimensional configuration in Euclidean space, such that these coordinates give rise to distances from $A$?
(high-dimensional configuration implies dimensionality at most $n-1$)

If this is generally not possible, what would be the conditions that have to be met in order to achieve a high-dimensional configuration giving rise to distances in $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From suitable linear combinations of the entries of the distance matrix (the matrix of *squared* distances) one can construct the Gram matrix of the direction vectors from one point (taken as zero) to the others. To be embeddable into a Euclidean space of dimension $r$, this matrix must be positive semidefinite of rank $r$; then the Cholesky factor provides an explicit embedding. (This is old stuff by Schoenberg, http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/1989894; see also my paper http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/scan/16.pdf and http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/scan/combcon.pdf)

If one allows a monotone transformation of the distances, an embedding is always possible: Simply add a large constant to all distances between distinct elements.

Related is the technique of multidimensional scaling;
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling

Comment: Bottomline: the embedding is not possible with an arbitrary symmetric matrix $A$ with zero diagonal and all remaining entries being positive. On the other hand, if we allow for addition of  constant $c$ to entries of $A$, the embedding in at most $n-1$ dimensional space is possible with large $c$.

Comment: ... to the nondiagonal entries